# Alternatives to format text of body email using MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, text

I have this code to send emails with Google Apps Script:

```
 var message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua " + name + "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris" + receiver;
 MailApp.sendEmail(email2Send, title, message);
```

But the email that goes to receiver has no formating, no paragraphs, etc. I would apreciate at least paragraphs (new lines) but \n doesn't work. The documentation tells me that:

> htmlBody  String  if set, devices capable of rendering HTML will use it
> instead of the required body argument; you can add an optional
> inlineImages field in HTML body if you have inlined images for your
> email

So, I could do something like this:

```
...
var options = {
  htmlBody: '<b><i>TEST</i></b>'
};
MailApp.sendEmail('someone@domain.ext', 'TEST', 'TEST', options);
...
```

What are the alternatives do add format to a message using `MailApp.sendEmail`? Could you suggest me one simple HTML templates to a basic text format? (I'd like something simpler than this [(Gmail) Sending emails from spreadsheet. How to add signature with image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493808/gmail-sending-emails-from-spreadsheet-how-to-add-signature-with-image))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\n` works.

```
MailApp.sendEmail("myemailbox@example.sinvalid","test","multi\nline\ntext");
```

send a mail with the following body:

```
multi 
line 
text
```

Comment: The first time I use \n I got `n` in the string. I think I use the wrong `/`. Thanks!

Comment: You could also set the body to HTML and throw in some html <BR> tags.

Comment: e.g. MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{'htmlBody' : content } );