# How to implement newline or carriage return using gmail to send text (sms) messages. \n newline character doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google scripts to send text messages. I would like to use the newline character to format messages properly. I would expect the code below to display:

Hello.
How are you?

Instead, the following is displayed:
Hello.How are you?

```
var response = "Hello.\nHow are you?"

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, response);
```

Please note recipient is in the format:
"(956) xxx-xxxx" <1740xxxxxxx.1956xxxxxxx.dhJVMRb1ZG@txt.voice.google.com>

That is, this is being sent as sms via gmail.

UPDATE, I tried:

```
function myFunction()
{
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
'(956) xxx-xxxx <1262xxxxxxx.1956xxxxxxx.7ljPdnVXKg@txt.voice.google.com>',
 'test mailApp', 'test3', { htmlBody: "break3<br />line"});
}
```

and the result was:

test3

which tells me that any email sent to txt.voice.google.com is processed as text only, not html. I hope there's some workaround.

Comment: I found another [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720832/line-break-in-a-message) article pertaining to this, but this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please note this [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742364/alternatives-to-format-text-of-body-email-using-google-apps-script-mailapp-send) article as well (reposted from my comment on a post below).

Comment: @ZigMandel no cigar, \r\n does not work either. they appear to be replaced with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

jimpudar's answer wont work!

The text of email will be "Hello.
How are you?"

Instead use this:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail("me@gmail.com", "Email", "This won't be displayed", { htmlBody:
                                                                                 "Hello</br>How are you?"
    }
);
```

Or you can do:

```
var recipient = "example@gmail.com";
var subject = "This email";
var body = "Hello.</br>How are you?";

    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "This won't be displayed",{htmlBody:
                   body                                                                 
        }
    );
```

Both will work ;)

As you maybe noticed, you can use any html code inside the {htmlBody: whatever}

Good luck, and have fun with scripting :)

Comment: Hello, I tried this:



MailApp.sendEmail({ to: sender, subject: timeNow, htmlBody: "Line <br> break."});



The output was:
Line break                //



Please note sender is in the format "(956) ###-####" <1740#######.1956#######.dhJVMRb1ZG@txt.voice.google.com>

Comment: I found an [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742364/alternatives-to-format-text-of-body-email-using-google-apps-script-mailapp-send) making the sames suggestion to use the <br> tag but I still cannot get this to work.

Comment: The slash in the break is wrong `</br> `. Either use no slash or put it at the end like `<br/>`.

Comment: Yeah, i copied it from wrong script, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this, but I seem to remember using HTML 
 tags to accomplish this.

```
var response = "Hello.<br>How are you?";
```

This probably won't work if your email is being sent as text. It worked for me when sending the text as an HTML email.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work as <br> gets displayed in the final sms message.