# Node.js gmail api image signature

Tags: node.js, image, gmail

How do you embed an image in an email using the [node.js gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)? I would like to use an image for my email signature. I tried html image tags e.g. `<img src='data:image/png;base64, ...'>`, but nothing appears in the email

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18493808/7108653

Comment: @Tanaike I'm using the gmail api https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my comment was not useful.